# PHP: How to get both key and value from an associative array?

Tags: php

I have this associative array structure:

```
$multiArray = array(
                 'key1' => array(1, 2, 3, 4),                
                 'key2' => array(5, 6, 7, 8),
                 'key3' => array(9, 10, 11, 12)
              );
```

When I call $multiArray['key1'], I get the value (which is normal):

```
// Example 1
$multiArray['key1'];
//$multiArray only has [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Is there a way that when I call I want $multiArray['key1'] that I can have `['key1' => array(1,2,3,4)]` or the other two keys, depending on the situation?

I could structure $multiArray like so, but I was wondering if there is a better way.

```
// Example 2
$multiArray = array(
                 'keyA' => array('key1' => array(1, 2, 3, 4)),  
                 'keyB' => array('key2' => array(5, 6, 7, 8)),
                 'keyC' => array('key3' => array(9, 10, 11, 12))
              );
$multiArray['keyA'];
// $multiArray is now what I want: ['key1' => [1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

Comment: Could you point out why you would need the key if you already access the array using a key? You may retrieve all array keys using `$arrKeys= array_keys($multiArray);`, does that help?

Comment: I think bcmcfc's answer about the getArray() function might be what I was looking for.  I just wasn't thinking clearly about what I wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
function getArray ($multiArray, $key) {
    return array($key => $multiArray[$key]);
}
```

or

```
$result = array('key1' => $multiArray['key1']);
```

A little more context as to how you're using it would be useful though. It sounds like you already know the requested key at the point of use. If not you may need to use [`array_keys`](http://php.net/array_keys).

Comment: I am trying to pass this variable to a function that I do not control, and it expects the data structure I was asking about.  I think your utility function is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you may be looking for is [`foreach`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php):

```
$myArray = array('key1' => array(1, 2, 3), 'key2' => array(4, 5, 6));
$multiArray = array();
foreach ($myArray as $key => $value) {
    // $key would be key1 or key2
    // $value would be array(1, 2, 3) or array(4, 5, 6)
    $multiArray[] = array($key => $value);
}
```

Comment: I'm not looking to take apart the array.  I need to restructure it.